# Using Airflow version 2.5.3 and Cloud Composer version 2.6.2, DAGs frequently throw this error of log file not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, logfile

Error message - "*** Log file is not found: 
*** The task might not have been executed, or the worker executing it might have finished abnormally (e.g., was evicted)."
Please, refer https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#common_issues hints to learn what might be possible for a missing log".

Tried to run DAGs but were not succeeding. It would extremely helpful if someone can assist on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the task was trying to run but failed half-way cause of OOM or worker eviction.

check serial logs any "OOM" or "CGgroup out of memory".